# A four term exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $ A \stackrel{f}→ B → C → 0 $ is an exact sequence then there is an isomorphism
$C ≃ Coker f$.

Some help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Exactness and the rightmost zero tell us that the map $B\to C$ is surjective (why?), so that $C\cong B/\{\ker B\to C\}$.  Now use exactness at $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of $C \to 0$ is the image of $g: B \to C$; therefore $g: B \to C$ is surjective. Therefore we have $C \cong B/\ker(g)$. The kernel of $g$ is the image of $f$. Etc.